# Firebase: Local Development and testing in AngularFire

Tags: firebase, google-oauth, angularfire, firebase-security

I am using Angularfire to make a website. I am trying to integrate `oauth` based sign in with `google` for user authentication but when I try to run `index.html` file and try to login following error is displayed

```
11:59:28.189 Error: There are no login transports available for the requested method.
Stack trace:
Mg@file:///G:/Project/root/js/firebase.js:142:1267
dh/<@file:///G:/Project/root/js/firebase.js:163:141
1 app.js:31:4
```

I searched on stackoverflow for this and got this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642300/firebase-angularfire-facebook-login-no-login-transports-available-error)  , it says that I need to setup a server for this. 
Then I looked at firebase docs and they said

> For security reasons, if you're using a web-based OAuth flow
>   (Facebook, Twitter, Github, or Google), only domains that you
>   whitelist are allowed to initiate authentication for your app. This
>   does not apply to Email & Password, Anonymous, or Custom
>   authentication methods. All Firebase applications have localhost and
>   127.0.0.1 enabled by default for local development and testing.

The authentication works fine after I host it on firebase but deploying takes a lot of time and also sometimes even I don't have access to internet. 
So please suggest me easiest manner so I can run my app on localhost.

Comment: I'm not getting any error logged. But after the user has logged in to Google and redirected back to my page, user object is still null (when I run this on localhost). If I upload the same code on a server it works perfectly well (I've whitelisted that domain). But deploying code to server after each change is really time consuming and would like to do development locally. Did you find solution to your problem?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to locally run a Firebase (or any other) web site is to use the [Firebase tools](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/command-line-tool.html) and then run

```
firebase serve
```

See this [blog post introducing the local server](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-13-google-login-and-firebase-cli-2.html).

Comment: I ran `firebase serve` command and then opened `localhost:5000` but it shows `cannot Get / .`

Comment: Sounds like a new Stack Overflow is in order then, and like you should include enough detail to [create an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).