# Can I run a local version of firebase database for development purposes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to not run the actual code on firebase database while development by firing up a local instance and developing using that, like we do for other mongodb and mysql databases?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this module [firebase-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-server)

> I built an open-source project called firebase-server to implement end-to-end tests in my own application. With firebase-server, my end-to-end tests are now running 40% faster and I no longer depend on an Internet connection for running the tests in development.
>
> Firebase Web Socket Protocol Server. Useful for emulating the Firebase server in tests.

```
var FirebaseServer =     require('firebase-server');

    new FirebaseServer(5000, 'localhost.firebaseio.test', {

    states: {
        CA: 'California',
        AL: 'Alabama',
        KY: 'Kentucky'
    }
});
```

client side

```
var client =    new Firebase('ws://localhost.firebaseio.test:5000');
client.on('value', function(snap) {
    console.log('Got value: ', snap.val());
});
```

For more details
[end-to-end-testing-with-firebase-server](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/04/end-to-end-testing-with-firebase-server_16.html)

[firebase-local-development-and-testing-in-angularfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671083/firebase-local-development-and-testing-in-angularfire)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Firebase Local Emulator Suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite):

> The Firebase Local Emulator Suite is a set of advanced tools for developers looking to build and test apps locally using Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database, Cloud Functions, Cloud Pub/Sub and Firebase Hosting.